# how to call shell script (.ksh) file from another shell script

Tags: shell-script

I am not able to call a shell script from another shell script.
I have written below code. The first script is getting executed (`extract_trig_to_in.ksh`)
but the second one `copy_to_dbload_path.ksh` is not getting executed.

```
sleep 2

. /opt/ontology/scripts/Green_DMS_Automation/sovan/c20_data_extraction_scripts/ksh/extract_trig_to_in.ksh

sleep 2

. /opt/ontology/scripts/Green_DMS_Automation/sovan/c20_data_extraction_scripts/ksh/copy_to_dbload_path.ksh
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages at all? Why is there no `#!`-line in the code that you show? Is there any reason you're sourcing the scripts rather than running them normally? What do the two scripts do? Is the first script using `exit` at any point (which would exit the calling script as well since you're sourcing the script rather than running it normally).

Comment: All I see is you successfully running two scripts. (and some sleeping, is this relevant). What is in the scripts? What errors do you get? What are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

`. Script.ksh` includes source of script into your one. And if there any "exit" command it will exit your script. Try to replace it with just `/bin/ksh Script`